# Infinitesimal Values

Tags: proof-explanation, infinity

Does the $0.\overline{9} = 1$ proof show that the gap between numbers adjacent numbers is $0$, and so are infinitesimal values equal to $0$ ? Would $10^{-\infty}=0$ ?

Edit: I feel like the smallest non-zero number would be $0.0...1$, which when subtracted from $1$ would 'appear' to be $0.999...$ , but it can't since $1 = 0.999...$

Comment: "the gap between **adjacent numbers**"  There is no such thing as "adjacent numbers."  Given two real numbers, either they are equal or they have a number between them.

Comment: $10^{-\infty}$ is not a valid expression.  $\infty$ is not a real number.  A related concept though that is valid to talk about is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}10^{-x}$ which is indeed zero.

Comment: Read up about the property of Reals that they are **Dense**.

Comment: But how can there be a number close to 1 than 0.999...?

Comment: "*but how can there be a number close to 1 than 0.999...*"  It is unclear what exactly you are asking here since your grammar is so poor, but if you mean to ask "how can there be a number *as close* to $1$ as $0.999\dots$" or "how can there be a number *closer* to $1$ than $0.999\dots$" remember that $0.999\dots$ **is** $1$, it just just another way of writing it.  When you have two *unequal* numbers, $a,b$ with $a<b$ then $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is a number unequal to either and inbetween them.

Comment: So does every number in between 0.999... and 1 also equal 1?

Comment: "*So does every number inbetween $1$ and $1$ also equal $1$*"  Yes.

Comment: I know that it does, I can't explain the question very well though, sorry. I feel like subtracting the smallest number from 1 would equal 0.999..., since the smallest number 'would' be 0.00....1, but 1 = 0.999...

Comment: See below.  There is no such thing as *the smallest number*.  Suppose that $\epsilon$ were such a "smallest number", but then $\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$ contradicting that $\epsilon$ be the smallest.

Comment: Stop! Just stop!  There are no such things as "adjacent numbers" and there is no gap between them, there is no smallest positive number.  Both $10^{-\infty}$ and $.000..... 0001$ are meaningless nonsense and don't mean anything.  $.\overline{9999}$ is $1$.  *EXACTLY* $1$.  Not "infinitely close to $1$", not "as close as you like to $1$", but *EXACTLY* equal to $1$.  $1 -.\overline{9999} = 0$, not something infinitely small but $0$.  Because $1 -1=0$.  And $.\overline{9999} = 1$ *EXACTLY*.  Dont' ask "but what if" or "how about".  Those are *absolute* facts.  Get used to it.

Comment: "I feel like the smallest non-zero number would be 0.0...1,"  Well, you feel wrong.  There is no such thing as a smallest non-zero number.  "which when subtracted from 1 would 'appear' to be 0.999..." you feel wrong.  There is not smallest number so you can't subtract it.  Anything that "appears" to be $0.9999....$ *IS* $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: $0.9999...= \dfrac{9}{10}+\dfrac{9}{100}+\cdots= \dfrac{\frac{9}{10}}{1-\dfrac{1}{10}}=1$. For the other question $10^{-\infty} = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to -\infty} 10^n = 0$ ( you can prove this using definition ) .

Comment: Would the bottom equation be equal to 0.0...1 if that number could exist?

Comment: I meant sort of like the smallest possible number. If you could minus that from 1 what would you get? Since the 'apparent' answer of 0.999... also equals 1. I know it probably doesn't have an answer but I couldn't wrap my head around it when I heard it.

Comment: @J.Doe "*the smallest possible number*."  You are describing an infinitesimal.  The **only** infinitesimal in standard real analysis is exact zero.  Any other real number could be halved giving a smaller real number.

Comment: That's why I was wondering if 10−∞=0 (since it would otherwise be infinitesimal) (and even though it is not a valid expression)

Comment: $10^{-\infty}$ is as you say, "not a valid expression."  That means that anything you say about it is *meaningless*.  It doesn't denote *anything*. There aren't any sensible questions you can ask about it.

Comment: But the answers says that its equal to that limit, which is equal to zero

Comment: @J.Doe $.000...1$ is not defined. Think of it this way. A decimal is a function that inputs a counting number $1, 2, 3, ...$ and outputs a digit. There is no end to the counting numbers so there is no "last decimal digit."

Comment: Simply remove *all* concepts of "the smallest number or $0.0000 ....1$ or $.\overline{9999}$ being anything different than $1$ from your head.  There is no such thing as "a smallest number" and $.\overline{9999}$ and $1$ are *ONE* thing.  The *exact* same thing.  $5 - 4 = .\overline{9999}$ and $.\overline{9999}\times 7 = 7$.  $1 = .\overline{9999}$.  PERIOD.  And $1-0 = .\overline{9999}$ and $.\overline{9999} -1 =0$ and $1 - .\overline{9999} = 0$ and $.\overline{9999} -1 = 0$.  Because statements are $1-0=1;1-1=0;1-1=0$ and $1-1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The real numbers do not contain infinitesimals. In systems with infinitesimals, it is not true that $0.\overline 9 = 1$, using its usual definition as series limit. Indeed, in systems with infinitesimals, $0.\overline9$ is actually undefined, as the series won't converge.

If you define $0.\overline 9$ differently, then in those systems it may or may not be equal to $1$, depending on the definition.

However note that the real numbers are *complete*, that is, all Cauchy sequences converge in them, and therefore there is no need to introduce infinitesimal values. Indeed, when considering convergence they are actually harmful.